# VBA - Copy chart from excel to powerpoint without link (embed)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a macro that copies all charts from my Excel sheet into a new PowerPoint file.

The problem is that the charts update themselves if I use a filter while the Excel file is open. To prevent it, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and embed it. But I do not know how to change my code to do the same (at the moment the code just "copies" it")

Does anyone know the correct form to use the special copy?

```
Sub ChartObjectsPowerpoint()
    Dim pptApp As Object, pptPres As Object
    Dim chtObj As Object, shp As Object, i
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(msoTrue)

    For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        chtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
        i = i + 1
        Set PPTSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(i, 12) '12 = ppLayoutBlank
        Set shp = PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
        shp.Top = 0
        shp.Left = 0
        shp.Width = 800
        shp.Height = 400
    Next

    pptApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To break the link between the charts copied to PowerPoint from Excel, you can use the following code taken from [TheSpreadsheetGuru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/9/25/break-all-external-links-powerpoint):

```
Sub BreakAllExcelLinks()
'PURPOSE: Break any external links in your PowerPoint presentation
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sld As Slide

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
      On Error Resume Next
        shp.LinkFormat.BreakLink
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next shp
  Next sld

End Sub
```

It will stop the charts from updating themselves.